# Resize Images inside grid - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have to show three images in a way that center image should have double width of left or right end views. The Imagesource to Left and right end have size of 335x377 and the center imagesource have size of 403x226.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">

       <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
       <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>          
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>          
       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" ></ColumnDefinition>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Image Name="ImageViewer1"  Stretch="None" />
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
        <Image Name="ImageViewer2"    Stretch="None" />
       </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
        <Image Name="ImageViewer3"   Stretch="None" />
      </StackPanel>

  </Grid
```

Shall I need to  define the size of 'ImageViewer' to achieve this ?

Comment: Try setting the `Stretch` property to `UniformToFill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the image widths do not more or less exactly match the column widths, it is obviously wrong to set

```
<Image Stretch="None" ... />
```

You would either set

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" ... />
```

to make the left and right images horizontally fill their columns, or

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill" ... />
```

to make them also fill the row height, but cut off a bit at their sides.

You could also remove the StackPanels:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <Image x:Name="ImageViewer1" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Image x:Name="ImageViewer2" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Image x:Name="ImageViewer3" Grid.Column="2" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Grid>
```